# Python/Django Modeling Question

Tags: python, database, django, model

What is the best way to have many children records pointing to one parent record in the same model/table in Django?

Is this implementation correct?:

```
class TABLE(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey("TABLE", unique=False)
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you don't need the id field, that'll be generated for you automatically as an auto-incrementing primary key field.

Comment: Also, the default value of unique is False, so you don't need that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Django has a special syntax for ForeignKey for self-joins:

```
class TABLE(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self')
```

[Source](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) (second paragraph)

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

First, you need to allow the possibility of a null value for `parent`, otherwise your `TABLE` tree can have no root.

Second, you need to worry about the possibility of "I'm my own grandpa."  For a lively discussion, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401118/foreignkey-form-restrictions-in-django).